# Jquery document ready function, after load function

Tags: jquery, load, ready

I have loaded in a form via jQuery. As a consequence the `$(document).ready(function()` that was applied to it no longer functions. How do we reestablish the function to the form after it has loaded in.

Content is loaded in:

```
$('.section.com').load(window.location.href + ' .section.com .tubs')
```

This therefore no longer functions:

```
$('#commentform').ajaxForm(function () {
    $('.commentslogic').load('<?php the_permalink();?> .commentslogic .inner', function () {
        $('.commentlist li:first').hide();
        $('.commentlist li:first').slideDown(400);
        $('.commentlist li:first').effect('highlight', {}, 800);
        $('#cloader').slideUp(400);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the form binding in a function so that you can reuse it:

```
function bindForm() {
  $('#commentform').ajaxForm(function() { 
    $('.commentslogic').load('<?php the_permalink();?> .commentslogic .inner', function(){
      $('.commentlist li:first').hide(); $('.commentlist li:first').slideDown(400); $('.commentlist li:first').effect('highlight', {}, 800); $('#cloader').slideUp(400);
    })
  });
}
```

Now you can call it both from the `ready` event, and as callback in the `load` method to bind the new form:

```
$('.section.com').load(window.location.href + ' .section.com .tubs', bindForm)
```

Comment: Not working. The page is still reloading. I could not put bindForm where you have because I have a function going on their anyway. So I called it like this... $('.section.com').load(window.location.href + ' .section.com .tubs', function(){ bindForm(); ......... }

Comment: @RobinKnight: That should work. Did you remember to call it from the `ready` event also?

Comment: Ok I have it working in Firefox but not in Chrome. The bindForm function when I put it into a document ready function Firebug says that bindForm is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into `.load`'s callback so it gets re-applied to replaced elements:

```
$('.section.com').load(window.location.href + ' .section.com .tubs', function() {
    $('#commentform').ajaxForm(function() { 

        // rest of code
    });
});
```